# 95% confidence interval of single proportion in pandas timeseries using statsmodel

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I have a time-series dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':['2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019'],
                       'total_count': [545,779,706,547,626,530,766,1235,1260,947], 
                       'rand_count':[96,184,148,154,160,149,124,274,322,301],
                       'rand_perc':[17.61,23.62,20.96,28.15,25.56,28.11,16.19,22.19,25.56,31.78]
                       })
```

Here;

```
df['rand_perc'] = (df['rand_count']/df['total_count'])*100
```

**Problem**:

I want to compute confidence interval for single proportion of `df['rand_count']` from `df['total_count']` ,in each row of `df` and plot `df['year']` vs `df['rand_perc']` with `CI` as errorbars.  I tried using **statsmodel** to compute CI for each row using the following code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

df['CI'] =  df[['total_count', 'rand_count']].apply(lambda row: sm.stats.proportion_confint(count = 
df['rand_count'], nobs = df['total_count'], alpha = 0.05), axis = 1)
```

But the result `df['CI']`looks very annoying with the tuple of all CIs in each row as;

```
0    ([0.14416430990026746, 0.2063732756491498, 0.1...
1    ([0.14416430990026746, 0.2063732756491498, 0.1...
2    ([0.14416430990026746, 0.2063732756491498, 0.1...
3    ([0.14416430990026746, 0.2063732756491498, 0.1...
4    ([0.14416430990026746, 0.2063732756491498, 0.1...
5    ([0.14416430990026746, 0.2063732756491498, 0.1...
6    ([0.14416430990026746, 0.2063732756491498, 0.1...
7    ([0.14416430990026746, 0.2063732756491498, 0.1...
8    ([0.14416430990026746, 0.2063732756491498, 0.1...
9    ([0.14416430990026746, 0.2063732756491498, 0.1...
Name: CI, dtype: object
```

**Desired result**

respective tuple of two elements in each row of `df['CI']` like:

```
(0.144164, 0.206373)
(0.179606, 0.243846)
(0.221421, 0.242859)
...................
```

And two separate columns `df[upper]` and `df[lower]` for upper and lower limit of the `df['CI']` respectively.

Your kind help would be highly appreciable.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: seems like you are using `apply` wrong, replace `df` with `row` under apply: `df[['total_count', 'rand_count']].apply(lambda row: sm.stats.proportion_confint(count = 
row['rand_count'], nobs = row['total_count'], alpha = 0.05), axis = 1)`

Comment: Most methods for those functions should be vectorized, but the return is a numpy array that needs to be put back in a DataFrame with the correct index by the user.

Comment: Thanks @anky , what a silly mistake. I did not notice that.... Yeah, it has to be that way. Thanks again for kind help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider assigning multiple columns which should line up by index since per [docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint.html):

> When a pandas object is returned, then the index is taken from the count.

```py
df['lower_CI'], df['upper_CI'] =  sm.stats.proportion_confint(
                                      count = df['rand_count'],
                                      nobs = df['total_count'],
                                      alpha = 0.05
                                  )
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I failed to think of such a simple yet nice way. It fixes my problem. Highly appreciated!